# pytorch DataLoader: `Tensors must have same number of dimensions`

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to fit an LSTM model in Pytorch. My data is too big to be read into memory and so I want to create mini-batches of data using the `DataLoader` function from Pytorch.

I have two features as input (`X1`, `X2`). I have one output feature (y). I am using 365 timesteps of `X1` & `X2` as features used to predict `y`.

The dimensions of my training array is:

`(n_observations, n_timesteps, n_features)` == `(9498, 365, 2)`

I don't understand why the code below isn't working because I have seen other examples where the X, y pairs have different numbers of dimensions ([LSTM for runoff modelling](https://github.com/kratzert/pangeo_lstm_example/blob/master/LSTM_for_rainfall_runoff_modelling.ipynb), [Pytorch's own docs](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html#iterating-through-the-dataset) )

## Minimum Reproducible Example

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

train_x = torch.Tensor(np.random.random((9498, 365, 2)))
train_y = torch.Tensor(np.random.random((9498, 1)))
val_x = torch.Tensor(np.random.random((1097, 365, 2)))
val_y = torch.Tensor(np.random.random((1097, 1)))
test_x = torch.Tensor(np.random.random((639, 365, 2)))
test_y = torch.Tensor(np.random.random((639, 1)))

train_dataset = (train_x, train_y)
test_dataset = (test_x, test_y)
val_dataset = (val_x, val_y)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=256)

iterator = train_dataloader.__iter__()
iterator.next()
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-2a0b28b53c8f> in <module>
     13 
     14 iterator = train_dataloader.__iter__()
---> 15 iterator.next()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    344     def __next__(self):
    345         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 346         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    347         if self._pin_memory:
    348             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
---> 47         return self.collate_fn(data)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py in default_collate(batch)
     53             storage = elem.storage()._new_shared(numel)
     54             out = elem.new(storage)
---> 55         return torch.stack(batch, 0, out=out)
     56     elif elem_type.__module__ == 'numpy' and elem_type.__name__ != 'str_' \
     57             and elem_type.__name__ != 'string_':

RuntimeError: invalid argument 0: Tensors must have same number of dimensions: got 4 and 3 at /tmp/pip-req-build-4baxydiv/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensor.cpp:680
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` must get a `torch.utils.data.Dataset` as parameters. You're giving a tuple of tensors. I suggest you use the `torch.utils.data.TensorDataset` as follows:

```py
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset

train_x = torch.rand(9498, 365, 2)     
train_y = torch.rand(9498, 1)

train_dataset = TensorDataset(train_x, train_y)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=256)

for x, y in train_dataloader:
    print (x.shape)
```

Check if it solves your problem.